# Getting a Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe') error

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, console.log

So I just made a component that has a method that, when clicked, will initiate a download. When executed in the browser, I noticed that while it works perfectly, however, when I open the console, it reports the error

```
core.js:6479 
    
   ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')
    at SafeSubscriber._next (navbar.component.ts:22:14)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183:1)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122:1)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72:1)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35:1)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35:1)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33:1)
```

Here's the code as follows:

```
    download() {
      customProtocolCheck(
        this.customProtocol,
        () => {
          this.urlSite.get().subscribe((link) =>
            this.openUrl(link.url).subscribe(
              () => {
                return;
              },
              (err: any) => {
                alert("Failed to start download!");
              }
            )
          );
        },
        () => {},
        5000
      );
  };
```

And the open URL code:

```
private openUrl(download_url: string): any {
    window.open(download_url, '_blank');
  }
```

If someone knows how I can fix that undefined subscribe, It'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: navbar.component.ts:22:14 is referring to this.openUrl(elements.url).subscribe if anyone is wondering.

Comment: Why are you subscribing to this.openUrl? This code doesn’t make much sense I’m afraid..

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it was completely unnecessary. I just fixed the code by removing that subscribe and moving the error. It's now fixed. Thanks.